# [SAS]Reading in Mixed Record types (.dat) with multiple levels in one data step

Tags: sas

I have a dataset (employeeinfo.dat) that looks like (note there's a lot more observations than just this) the following:

```
(Level1) Chief Executive Officer  (Anthony Miller )                                                    $433,800
     (Level2) Chief Sales Officer  (Harry Highpoint )                                                  $243,190
              (Level3) Vice President  (Henri Le Bleu )                                                $194,885
                       (Level4) Director  (Reginald Steiber )                                          $156,065
                                (Level5) Sales Manager  (Dennis Lansberry )                             $84,260
                                         (Level6) Sales Rep. I  (Saunders Briggi )                      $26,335
                                (Level5) Senior Sales Manager  (Louis Favaron )                         $95,090
                                         (Level6) Sales Rep. I  (Harold Boulus )                        $26,035
```

I need to read this into SAS such that I can split the data into the following variables: Level, Job Title, Name, and Salary.

My issue is that different levels are indicated (with no set pattern) throughout the data. Meaning, I cannot take for granted that any of the variables start at any specific place (column) in the data being input nor can I specify a length for most of the variables since they vary.

Here's my feeble attempt (I at least loaded in the first entry correctly) just to make sure I have a grasp on the concept at all:

```
data emp;
    infile 'employeeinfo.dat';
    input @1 position $9.
          @10 jobtitle $24.
          @35 name $72.
          @108 salary dollar8.;
run;
```

This loads the first entry in correctly, but is obviously useless for the rest.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Note: I have one constraint in doing this. The text I'm using states that the objective of this exercise is to give experience working with fixed width raw data files that have no delimiters. The solution must have multiple input statements with pointer controls.

Answer (score 1):

The gap between job title and name is always at least two spaces, and likewise between name and salary.  When input fields have two or more spaces between them the list `input` style `&` argument uses two spaces as end of value marker, and thus will read those field values containing a single space between the words. The `:` argument on `salary` will scan for a value starting at next non-blank to next blank or end-of-line.

```
filename have 'c:\temp\sample.txt';

data want;
  attrib
    level length=$10
    position length=$50
    name length=$30
    salary length=8
  ;
  infile have missover;
  input  
    level
    position&
    name&
    salary: dollar. ;
  ;
run;
```

The `level` and `name` values can be cleaned up using the `compress` function:

```
level = compress(level,'()');
name = compress(name,'()');
```

Comment: Hi Richard, I believe this is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. It worked for almost all of the records (rows). However, it attributed a missing value to a salary that should not be missing on one row. I think due to the nature of the '&' argument. I wish there was someway I could post the entire dataset to show this.

Comment: Real world data rarely conforms to expected data model.  The errant row likely does not have two-space gap expected.  An alternate strategy would be to use infile `DLM="()"` to use parenthesis as the field separators and remove the & and : arguments. Then your real-world might be having some rows that are not consistent with parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah, looking more closely, the errant row has a double space in the "name" column between first and last name. Hence why salary comes up as missing, because the last name is being read as the salary.